# Efficient element by element multiplication of 3D matrix elements with copies of a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to multiply each element(say `[i,j]`) of a `MxN` 2D matrix(say `A`) to to all elements in the 3D row of a 3D matrix(say `B`), so `B[i,j,:]`. The following doesn't help because it gives me a `(2,3,3)` shaped matrix rather than `(3,3,2)`. Plus, I think for such a multiplication making a copy is redundant. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
B=np.ones((3,3,2))
A=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
c=np.tile(A,(2,1,1))
print np.multiply(a,c)
```

The output I expect is:

```
[[[1,1]],[[2,2]],[[3,3]],[[4,4]][[5,5]],[[6,6]],[[7,7]],[[8,8]],[[9,9]]]
```

Comment: My code doesn't work. Cant broadcast... I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output (after adding a comma) would have shape `(9, 1, 2)` if passed to `array`.  Assuming that's a mistake, and you do want an array of shape `(3,3,2)` with those values, then I think all you need to do is extend `A`:

```
>>> A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
>>> B = np.ones((3,3,2))
>>> C = A[..., None] * B
>>> C
array([[[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  4.],
        [ 5.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  6.]],

       [[ 7.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  8.],
        [ 9.,  9.]]])
>>> C.shape
(3, 3, 2)
```